# PHP contact form multiple recipients, recipient list dependent on user choice - checkboxes

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I want to make the contact form on my website to choose recipients of the message, based on what checkboxes are checked by the user.

The user can choose minimum one recipient (1 checkbox checked), up to twelve recipients (12 people available to ask the question - it is the user's choice who he wants to contact).

Since I am not very skilled with php, I will highly appreciate your help.

Here is the html:

```
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="1"></div>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="2"></div>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="3"></div>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="4"></div>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="5"></div>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="6"></div>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="7"></div>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="8"></div>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="9"></div>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="10"></div>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="11"></div>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group1" value="12"></div>
```

And here is the php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "me@mydomain.com";

    $email_subject = "";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "";
        echo "";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died(');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= '';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= '';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= '';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

       $email_message .='

//html structure of email goes here
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- success html here -->
<?php
}
die();
?>
```

The code in it's current state is working just fine (I removed error messages and html structure of email since it is irrelevant - would only take space) but with fixed recipients (while they are provided in the code here `$email_to`).

I want to change the code so that:

- user chooses the recipient of his message, there are 12 choices, min=1, max=12.
- the choice will be made by checking checkboxes
- every checkbox is assigned to specific email

Sorry for repeating myself again in this "conclusion" - I wanted it to be as clear as possible. Also, sorry for my trivial question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values of checkbox were the e-mails, you just need to use implode()
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php

```
$emails = implode(",",$_REQUEST['group1']);
$email_to = $emails;
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use this solution. I had to change "group1" into "group1[]" in html code - now works fine.